# Calling one overloaded method from another to build ViewModel C#/ ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, overloading

Semi-new to ASP.NET MVC and programming in general. I have a method which builds a ViewModel that I use in most of my other Views and has two overloads.  I wanted to call the first overload from the second overload to be more efficient, so I did this:

```
public HeaderViewModel BuildHeaderViewModel(int? chainId, int? sheetId)
{
    HeaderViewModel header = new HeaderViewModel();

    header.ChainName = db.Chains.Find(chainId).Name;
    header.SheetName = db.Sheets.Find(sheetId).Name;
    header.SheetDescription = db.Sheets.Find(sheetId).Description;

    return header;
}

public HeaderViewModel BuildHeaderViewModel(int? chainId, int? sheetId, int? fileId)
{
    HeaderViewModel header = new HeaderViewModel();

    header = BuildHeaderViewModel(chainId, sheetId); // calling first overload

    var fileDetails = db.FileDetails.Find(fileId);
    header.SheetFileName = fileDetails.Name + fileDetails.Extension;

    return header;
}
```

My question is, is this the correct / most efficient way of doing this? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The common pattern is to have the constructor that takes the least argument call the constructor that takes the most arguments. Typically using `: this(...)`.

Comment: Good point. Only, "constructor" seems to have been used in error. These are just methods. I think the OP mean't "constructor" as in these methods create and return an object instance, but that's obviously not the correct term.

Comment: I did give an effort at looking into ``: this``, but I really didn't understand.  I think because I had it backwards, having the constructor with the most arguments calling the least arguments. Also, thanks for clarifying my terminology @ChrisPratt!

Comment: `: this` would only be applicable with actual constructor overloads, as in class constructors. You wouldn't use it with something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the *typical* way to use chain overloads is to have the majority of the logic in the most specific one and deal with optional values appropriately:

```
public HeaderViewModel BuildHeaderViewModel(int? chainId, int? sheetId)
{
    return BuildHeaderViewModel(chainId, sheetId, null);
}

public HeaderViewModel BuildHeaderViewModel(int? chainId, int? sheetId, int? fileId)
{
    HeaderViewModel header = new HeaderViewModel();

    header.ChainName = db.Chains.Find(chainId).Name;
    header.SheetName = db.Sheets.Find(sheetId).Name;
    header.SheetDescription = db.Sheets.Find(sheetId).Description;

    if(fileId.HasValue)
    {
        var fileDetails = db.FileDetails.Find(fileId);
        header.SheetFileName = fileDetails.Name + fileDetails.Extension;
    }
    return header;
}
```

The main difference is that your *current* method does nothing different if `fileId` is null, which may be OK, in which case you can take the null check out of the overload.

Comment: I like this much more.  Thanks!  I will be using this way in the future, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with calling a method from another overload version of it - I've seen it done, and was able to see the intention pretty easily.

You are basically saying "If I have the fileId, I'd like to also initialize the FileDetails object, too!"

Makes sense to me :)